# Creating a fake microphone to use/dump audio to

Tags: java, audio

I have created a voice synthesizer. It works very well, and in real time, but my only problem is that my program is set to output to my speakers, not to the microphone. How do I create a "false" microphone that is purely the effects, so I could go to say, Discord, and select this as one of my microphones?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be a simple case of selecting the computer line's out (that goes to the speakers) when you set your input audio on the call. I also wonder if there might be some clues to be gained via inspecting code at open source java jitsi.org project? It's kind of like "show screen" also, maybe if you go to show screen and have the voice synth application running on screen you will also get the sound output?